# latex beamer How to get rid of the shorttitle in frameheader of titlepage?

Tags: beamer, frame-title

I'm trying to adapt a pptx template of our agencies corporate design to latex beamer. Most things work as expected but I'm stuck at one problem.
The normal frametitle consists of max. two lines of title under the smalller shorttitle of the presentation, aligned to a coloured inset on the left side.
This works as expected.
The titlepage-frametitel consists of our agencies claim + logo, both aligned to an inset on the right side. 
I'm failing on removing the shorttitle from the titlepage-frametitle, although I'm defining the shorttitle in die frametitel-definition on just being a blank in order to keep the overoll alignment in the frametitle.

Thanks in advance
joachim

Code:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\makeatletter
\usetheme{Malmoe}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{winfont}
%\usecolortheme{angel}
%\usepackage{nubacolors}
%\usecolortheme{seagull}
\definecolor{greenRGB}{RGB}{94,173,53}
\definecolor{dgreenRGB}{RGB}{0,118,38}
\definecolor{lgrayRGB}{RGB}{240,241,241}
\definecolor{dgrayRGB}{RGB}{75,75,77}

\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}
%höhe der Titelzeilen
\newlength{\testheight}
\settoheight{\testheight}{\vbox{\small\hbox{t}\Large\hbox{T}\hbox{T}}}
% höhe des farbigen Einschubes am Seitenrand
\newlength{\sbheight}
\settoheight{\sbheight}{\testheight-\baselineskip+\depthof{\Large g}}
%\usepackage{ubaslides}


\colorlet{lightgray}{lgrayRGB}
\colorlet{darkgray}{dgrayRGB}
\colorlet{dark}{dgreenRGB}
\colorlet{normal}{greenRGB}
%Graue Linie für head oder footline
\newcommand{\horizontalgrayline}{
\begin{minipage}[t]{\paperwidth}
\colorbox{lightgray}{\parbox[4mm]{\paperwidth}{\ \hfill}}\par
\end{minipage}
}
% Seitenrand ohne Einschub
\newcommand{\sidenoinset}{%
\colorbox{lightgray}{\parbox[t][\paperheight]{0.07cm}{\hfill\strut}}
}
% Seitenrand mit farbigem Einschub bei title
\newcommand{\sideinset}{%
\colorbox{lightgray}{\parbox[t][0.07cm]{0.07cm}{\strut}}\par
\colorbox{dark}{\parbox[t][\testheight-\baselineskip+\depthof{\Large g}]{0.07cm}{\strut}}\par
\colorbox{lightgray}{\parbox[t][\paperheight-1.5cm]{0.07cm}{\strut}}
}
\newcommand*{\event}[1]{\gdef\@subject{#1}}
\event{test}
\newcommand*{\showevent}{\@subject}
%
%standardframekopf
%
\defbeamertemplate{frametitle}{stdslide}{
\begin{minipage}[t]{\paperwidth}
\usebeamerfont{frametitle}{\small\insertshorttitle\par}
\insertframetitle
\end{minipage}
}
%
% framekopf für Titelpage mit Logo
%
%\newcommand{\titlepageframetitle}{\Large Für Mensch \& Umwelt\hspace{3.012cm}{\raisebox{-0.71cm}[0.0cm][0.0cm]{\includegraphics[height=1.61cm]{logo_gruen.jpg}}}}
\newcommand{\titlepageframetitle}{\Large Für Mensch \& Umwelt\hspace{3.012cm}{LOGO}}

%
\defbeamertemplate{frametitle}{titlepage} {%
\titlepageframetitle
\begin{minipage}[t]{\paperwidth}
% insert blank to adjust height
\usebeamerfont{frametitle}{\small\ \par}
\insertframetitle
\end{minipage}
}
%
% titlepage
\newcommand{\titlelayout}{%
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=dgreenRGB,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}\usebeamercolor*[fg]{normal text}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\horizontalgrayline}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas left}{}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}{%
\sidenoinset
}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas right}{}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}{%
\sideinset
\usebeamertemplate*{frametitle}[titlepage]

}
}
%end titlelayout

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
%\begin{frame}
%\Large Für Mensch \& Umwelt
%\end{frame}
%\vspace*{-2em} Für Mensch \& Umwelt\par
{\large\textcolor{normal}\showevent\par}
{\Huge\inserttitle\par}
\medskip\insertauthor\par
}
\renewcommand{\makebeamertitle}{{\titlelayout
\frame{{\titlepageframetitle}\maketitle}}}

%ende titelpage
%
\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=0.2cm}
\setbeamersize{sidebar width right=0.2cm}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{fg=dgreenRGB}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\paperwidth}{\textcolor{white}{\hspace*{1cm}\insertdate \qquad \showevent \hfill\insertframenumber\hspace*{1cm}}}}
}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\horizontalgrayline
}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[stdslide]
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas left}{}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}{%
\sideinset
}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas right}{}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}{%
\sidenoinset
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}

\event{conference on testslides}

\title[Testslides]{Presentation-Testslides}

\author{Max Mustermann}

\institute{}
\makebeamertitle
\begin{frame}{very long frametitle on two lines\\
Test-long}
\begin{enumerate}
\item this
\item that 
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your MWE does not compile: `\makebeamertitle undefined. \renewcommand{\makebeamertitle}`

Answer (score 1):

Minimal damage proposal:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\makeatletter
\usetheme{Malmoe}
\usepackage{calc}
%\usepackage{winfont}
%\usecolortheme{angel}
%\usepackage{nubacolors}
%\usecolortheme{seagull}
\definecolor{greenRGB}{RGB}{94,173,53}
\definecolor{dgreenRGB}{RGB}{0,118,38}
\definecolor{lgrayRGB}{RGB}{240,241,241}
\definecolor{dgrayRGB}{RGB}{75,75,77}

\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}
%höhe der Titelzeilen
\newlength{\testheight}
\settoheight{\testheight}{\vbox{\small\hbox{t}\Large\hbox{T}\hbox{T}}}
% höhe des farbigen Einschubes am Seitenrand
\newlength{\sbheight}
\settoheight{\sbheight}{\testheight-\baselineskip+\depthof{\Large g}}
%\usepackage{ubaslides}


\colorlet{lightgray}{lgrayRGB}
\colorlet{darkgray}{dgrayRGB}
\colorlet{dark}{dgreenRGB}
\colorlet{normal}{greenRGB}
%Graue Linie für head oder footline
\newcommand{\horizontalgrayline}{
\begin{minipage}[t]{\paperwidth}
\colorbox{lightgray}{\parbox[4mm]{\paperwidth}{\ \hfill}}\par
\end{minipage}
}
% Seitenrand ohne Einschub
\newcommand{\sidenoinset}{%
\colorbox{lightgray}{\parbox[t][\paperheight]{0.07cm}{\hfill\strut}}
}
% Seitenrand mit farbigem Einschub bei title
\newcommand{\sideinset}{%
\colorbox{lightgray}{\parbox[t][0.07cm]{0.07cm}{\strut}}\par
\colorbox{dark}{\parbox[t][\testheight-\baselineskip+\depthof{\Large g}]{0.07cm}{\strut}}\par
\colorbox{lightgray}{\parbox[t][\paperheight-1.5cm]{0.07cm}{\strut}}
}
\newcommand*{\event}[1]{\gdef\@subject{#1}}
\event{test}
\newcommand*{\showevent}{\@subject}
%
%standardframekopf
%
\defbeamertemplate{frametitle}{stdslide}{
\begin{minipage}[t]{\paperwidth}
\usebeamerfont{frametitle}{\small\insertshorttitle\par}
\insertframetitle
\end{minipage}
}
%
% framekopf für Titelpage mit Logo
%
%\newcommand{\titlepageframetitle}{\Large Für Mensch \& Umwelt\hspace{3.012cm}{\raisebox{-0.71cm}[0.0cm][0.0cm]{\includegraphics[height=1.61cm]{logo_gruen.jpg}}}}
\newcommand{\titlepageframetitle}{\Large Für Mensch \& Umwelt\hspace{3.012cm}{LOGO}}

%
\defbeamertemplate{frametitle}{titlepage} {%
%\titlepageframetitle
\begin{minipage}[t]{\paperwidth}
% insert blank to adjust height
\usebeamerfont{frametitle}{\small\ \par}
\insertframetitle
\end{minipage}
}
%
% titlepage
\newcommand{\titlelayout}{%
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=dgreenRGB,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}\usebeamercolor*[fg]{normal text}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\horizontalgrayline}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas left}{}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}{%
\sidenoinset
}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas right}{}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}{%
\sideinset
%\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[titlepage]

}
}
%end titlelayout

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
%\begin{frame}
%\Large Für Mensch \& Umwelt
%\end{frame}
%\vspace*{-2em} Für Mensch \& Umwelt\par
{\large\textcolor{normal}\showevent\par}
{\Huge\inserttitle\par}
\medskip\insertauthor\par
}
\newcommand{\makebeamertitle}{{
    \titlelayout
    \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[titlepage]
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{\titlepageframetitle}
        \maketitle
    \end{frame}
}}

%ende titelpage
%
\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=0.2cm}
\setbeamersize{sidebar width right=0.2cm}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{fg=dgreenRGB}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\paperwidth}{\textcolor{white}{\hspace*{1cm}\insertdate \qquad \showevent \hfill\insertframenumber\hspace*{1cm}}}}
}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\horizontalgrayline
}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[stdslide]
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas left}{}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}{%
\sideinset
}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas right}{}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}{%
\sidenoinset
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}

\event{conference on testslides}

\title[Testslides]{Presentation-Testslides}

\author{Max Mustermann}

\institute{}
\makebeamertitle
\begin{frame}{very long frametitle on two lines\\
Test-long}
\begin{enumerate}
\item this
\item that 
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

For a cleaner solution I'd suggest to define a `title page` template instead of all these redefinitions of `\maketitle`

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charme. @samcarter, you are absolutely right with the title-template. I'm just starting to grasp the template mechanism :-)